# wp_insert_post order problem

Tags: wp-insert-post

I’m sorry, I speak a little English.

My code in my custom theme (functions.php) [only example]:

```
$posts = array(
'141th',
// ...
'3rd',
'2nd',
'1st'
);
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
wp_insert_post( array( 'post_title'=> $post ) );
}
```

My posts list:

```
1
4
3
2
5
...
141
```

I would like (in order):

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
141
```

Why? What is the problem and how to solving?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, from what I could tell, you just need to ensure the `$posts` array items are sorted in the order you've specified. But that is a generic PHP question and better suited on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Dear @SallyCJ, my $posts array is okay. I used the krsort( $posts ) function. I checked with print_r() function. My $posts variable is okay.

Comment: How and where are you viewing the posts where they are not in the order you are expecting?

Comment: @luckyluck31 even so, I don't think this is a `wp_insert_post()` issue - and just to remind you that `ksort()` sorts from highest to lowest. And if you're actually referring to the post list on pages like the homepage, then the posts would by default be sorted by the post date, from newest to oldest ones. So if you wanted to know how to change that, then you should edit your question and include as much details as possible like where the post list is, the template used on that page and the code which outputs the post list.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I just set my own value for the "post_date" field in the wp_insert_post function.

As an example:

```
$time = time();
for ($i=0; $i < count($postArgs); $i++) { 
    $postArg = $postArgs[$i];
    $postArg['post_date'] = $time-$i;
    wp_insert_post($postArg);
}
```